# ERROR AL USAR PIP INSTALL PYQT5-TOOLS

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt, pip

Intento usar el "Diseñador" del PYQT5 y lo hago instalando de esta manera:

1. PyQt5 | pip install pyqt5
2. PyQt5-tools | pip install pyqt5-tools
   Pero al instalar el segundo siempre me sale un error:
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y no me permite seguir, lo he intentado todo, hasta descargando el archivo, utilizando otros instaladores como Conda, pero nada. Igual estoy aún aprendiendo, si alguien me ayuda le agradeceré mucho.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré una alternativa, luego de luchar mucho; a decir verdad no recuerdo muy bien todo lo que hice, pero para que sirva de ayuda tuve que instalar Pyside2: https://pypi.org/project/PySide2/

Luego vas a donde instalaste el Python, buscas las siguientes carpetas:

```
Lib -> site-packages -> PySide2
```

Y en esa carpeta vas a encontrar la aplicación: designer.

Recuerda que debes tener instalado el PYQT5: https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/

Observación: No siempre se deberá comenzar en la carpeta LIB, en otros compañeros estaba en la carpeta libs

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta. Recuerda además que [es.so] no es un foro: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.